# dynamically remove, modify rows in oracle database using python

Tags: python, database, oracle

I have an oracle table- Students.
I want to be able to delete and modify rows dynamically.

an a table example:

| student id | course | grade | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | math | 90 | 2020 |
| :--------- | :------: | :-----: | -----: |
| 222 | French | 80 | 2021 |
| :--------- | :------: | :-----: | -----: |
| 333 | physics | 77 | 2015 |
| :--------- | :------: | :-----: | -----: |
| 444 | sport | 65 | 2014 |

and i want dynamiclly delete some row using python lets say row 3 the output should be:

| student id | course | grade | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | math | 90 | 2020 |
| :--------- | :------: | :-----: | -----: |
| 222 | French | 80 | 2021 |
| :--------- | :------: | :-----: | -----: |
| 444 | sport | 65 | 2014 |

*code
for delete row.

table_variables=[student_id , course, grade, year]

---

login path

---

```
c = conn.cursor()
        id=3
    
        statement =  ('delete from Students '
           'where rownum = :rownum')
        c.execute(statement,[id])
        conn.commit()
```

or i want just to modify an existing row using python for example:

| student id | course | grade | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | math-2 | 100 | 2020 |
| :--------- | :------: | :-----: | -----: |
| 222 | French | 80 | 2021 |
| :--------- | :------: | :-----: | -----: |
| 333 | physics | 77 | 2015 |
| :--------- | :------: | :-----: | -----: |
| 444 | sport | 65 | 2014 |

*code
for modify row.

---

login path

---

```
table_variables=[student_id , course, grade, year]
 c = conn.cursor()
        id=1
    
        statement =  ('update Students '
           'where student_id = :student_id ' and
course=:course and grade=:grade and year=:year
)
        c.execute(statement,[111,math-2,100,2020       ])
        conn.commit()
```

hope you can help i didnt find something online.

thanks!

Comment: 1. SQL table have no inherent order of rows. It is a set. 2. `update` should have `set` part of SQL statement. Otherwise what should be updated with what?

Comment: delete from .... where rownum=3 will not delete anything (it does not give an error, just says that zero rows where deleted), you need to use something like delete from .... where student_id=... and .... As for the update, your code will give you a python error, as your statement is not correct.

Comment: im trying to build database app, to be able to delete/insert/update specific rows